# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3n}{3n-1})^{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Regarding this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3n}{3n-1})^{n!}$

I need to tell if it converges or diverges.

Here is my attempt:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3n}{3n-1})^{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3n-1+1}{3n-1})^{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{3n-1})^{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((1+\frac{1}{3n-1})^{3n-1})^{\frac{n!}{3n-1}}$

So the limit inside is $\to e$, but how do I compute a limit of $n!$? I don't think its possible, so I might have gone lost here.

EDIT:

I can say that $x(x-1) \le \frac{x!}{3x-1}$, so by toast theorem $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!}{3x-1}= \infty$, so the limit $\to e^\infty = \infty$ ?

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: $t_n\ge1$ leaves little doubt.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is $t_n$?

Comment: The general term.

Comment: You answered your question since the limit of general term goes to infinity . So by using the divergent test the series would be divergent.

Comment: "toast theorem" is definitely the way I'm going to call it from now on! I like the name very much.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon haha! This is how we call it in class :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3n}{3n-1}\right)^{n!}\ge\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1.$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that my answer also works in this case?

Comment: @MathLover: IMO your answer is inappropriate because it misses the obvious.